# How to get AEM workflow process step Argument Values inside java Service?

Tags: java, aem

I crated a workflow on this process step Arguments field is there.
i am passing some string that field to java  ex: "welcome"

How can I get that value inside my Java service?

Java service here:

```
public void execute(WorkItem arg0, WorkflowSession arg1, MetaDataMap arg2) 
    throws WorkflowException {  
                     //Here i need my argument values

                             }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the Answer

```
public void execute(WorkItem item, WorkflowSession session, MetaDataMap args) throws WorkflowException {
        if (args.containsKey("PROCESS_ARGS")){
            log.info("workflow metadata for key PROCESS_ARGS and value {}",args.get("PROCESS_ARGS","string").toString());
        }       
    }
```